# Google Analytics funnel only shows exits for first step

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics funnel is only showing entrances and exits for the first step. All the inbetween steps have 0 entrances and 0 exits, but still show a hit count and a 100% conversion rate.

I'm trying to track an Enhanced Ecommerce purchase path funnel, from cart to confirmation.

I'm using tag manager and firing event tags to pass the data to analytics. on my shipping/payment/review pages I fire an event via a script, w

The script I fire for the ecommerce step looks like this:

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; 
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'checkout_review',
  'ecommerce': {'checkout': {'actionField" { 'step': 3}}}
})

[Existing funnel configuration, issue, and fired tag code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxV1m.jpg).

What I would expect is that there is are at least exits for my funnel steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the option "**Begin with**". This option is also assigned to individual steps in the funnel. The problem is that all your step start with "*shop.aap.org/cart/*". Therefore when Analytics verifies the correspondence with the paths it always finds it at the first step and stops there.

For the functioning of that particular funnel, the sessions they convert also fill all the previous steps.

If you want to learn more, I wrote some days ago an article that explains your problem exactly:
https://www.analyticstraps.com/quando-la-visualizzazione-canalizzazione-mente/
note: the article is in Italian, translate it into your language if necessary.

In your case you can try using "**Regex**" instead of "**Begin with**" and adjusting paths accordingly.